# Hibernate org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I created a Hibernate application using Eclips Maven project. It works fine. Then i created a another project and import that hibernate project and try to save object from that main project. So then it give me below excetion

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: io.klaver.core.model.WorkSpace; msg: Unknown entity:

I have added the Hibernate.cfg.xml in the correct place in library project. So what is the reason for this

Comment: cited entity is not known. IMPOSSIBLE to answer more without code and configuration

Comment: did you package structure change when you created the new project? Are you scanning the correct packages in your new project? Like @JacekCz mentioned, please share your code and config. Need more details to debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Import the project as an existing maven project.

And then make sure you have the `EntityName.hbm.xml`.

And in the `Hibernate.cfg.xml` add:

```
<!-- List of XML mapping files -->
<mapping resource="com/sow/application/EntityName.hbm.xml"/>
```